# SafeArray cannot be marshaled to this array type because it has either nonzero lower bounds or more than one dimension

Tags: c#, vb6, dynamic-arrays

SafeArray cannot be marshaled to this array type because it has either nonzero lower bounds or more than one dimension.

My VB6 Code snippet to call has dynamic array as ref parameter

```
Public Function DoEvaluation(**ByRef dynamicArr()** As Currency, Optional ByVal 
acm As Currency, Optional ByVal ytd As Currency, Optional 
lspsAs Long = 1) As Boolean
```

My C# Code snippet for calling above Vb6 code

```
decimal[] **dynamicAmt** = new decimal[11];
ok = Helper.DoEvaluation(ref **dynamicAmt** , acm, ytd, ref nps);
```

I am getting excetiption **"SafeArray cannot be marshaled to this array type because it has either nonzero lower bounds or more than one dimension."**

Please help how to call the Vb6 code from C# with dynamic array declared as ref parameter in Vb6.

Comment: Does your VB6 code assign to `dynamicArr` an array with nonzero lower bounds?

Comment: Yes, we are resizing and assigning values to this,     ReDim cPAmt(1 To mlNOP) As Currency

Comment: What do you think `"SafeArray cannot be marshaled to this array type because it has either nonzero lower bounds or more than one dimension."` means? _Keep in mind you are using a nonzero lower bound._

Comment: In Vb6 we can define array without length but in C# it must have some definite size.

Comment: Not exactly, i am more likely c# guy, just trying to call VB6 code from c#. Is there any way to call this VB6 code from  c# without modifying it in VB6 code.

Comment: `ReDim cPAmt(1 To mlNOP) As Currency` In that code, `1` is the lower bound. Change it to `0`.

Comment: Actually, the above solution needs fix in VB6 code which is legacy code and we don't want to change in this. If we can do some fix from C# to call this code??